# Should I learn bootstrap or skip to react?

Tags: frontend

I'm a beginner in frontend. I'm kinda stuck in all the possibilities.
I've already invested a lot of time learning HTML, CSS and I'm starting to learn JS. Should I learn bootstrap? On the one hand, it looks quite sharp. On the other hand, it's only a CSS framework, maybe it's a waste of time for me. In addition, colors are predifined and some people say that all bootstrap projects look similar. But allegedly 20% of websites are build with bootstrap.

Maybe I should finish JS and focus on React instead or on jQuery? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a newbie, I'm currently in a bootcamp. We learned bootstrap, then we started learning vanilla JS, and are currently starting to learn JQuery and then React.

When I was first introduced to Bootstrap, I thought it was lame and unnecessary. However, when I started answering practice problems that involved mocking up a quick website, I found that I loved grabbing a Bootstrap solution -- ex. a quick Nav Bar, some Cards, etc. -- to give a simple and clean visual effect.

I'm a newbie myself, but if you want to be able to draft up a quick webpage that looks nice, and don't mind using a premade style, I highly recommend mucking around with some Bootstrap.

If you only want to learn about backend, then it doesn't really matter I suppose, and go ahead and skip it. I find it very fun and empowering to be able to launch a quick and nice-looking webpage, though.